# Spring WebFlow2 fronting with Apache2 SSL produce http urls instead of https

Tags: apache2, tomcat7, spring-webflow

I have Apache2 SSL which is fronting Spring webapp as follows:

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/

ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

All works fine... i mean all links ... are correct, and in general webapp works, so the problem is not a matter of an application or SSL..

Except starting/cancelling webflows: they produce http URLs instead of https://

I found one topic here:

forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?70730-Webflow-2-0-and-reverse-proxy

They say it is not a problem of Spring WebFlow...

What is a workaround in this situation?

Comment: Well, the workaround was to substitute HTTP Proxying with AJP as follows:

At least, the problem has gone away after that...

    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing that all requests to the Tomcat connector are received via SSL terminated at httpd then you can add the following to your connector:

```
scheme="https" secure="true"
```

This tells Tomcat to treat the connection as if it was received over an SSL connection direct to Tomcat. This is required when proxying over http since there is no mechanism within http to pass the SSL info to Tomcat. There are ways to pass some of this info via http headers. Look at the SSLValve docs in Tomcat.

Alternatively, using AJP will work since AJP passes SSL information from httpd to Tomcat.